# Getting image extension

Tags: java, android, image, gallery, uri

In the application the user can select an image. To start the gallery I use the following code:

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
startActivityForResult(i, ACTIVITY_SELECT_IMAGE);
```

When I print the path in onActivityResult method, I get the image path like `/external/images/media/5615`. I'd like to know the image extension, because the image needs to be uploaded to a server. The extension may vary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're getting is a path the MediaStore uses to get the Images. The following code will take the result from your Intent, and get the filename attached to it:

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == ACTIVITY_SELECT_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {
            Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
            Log.i(TAG, "" + selectedImage.toString());
            String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                    filePathColumn, null, null, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();

            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
            String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
            cursor.close();

            Log.i(TAG, "" + picturePath);

            //Do whatever with picturePath

        }
```